# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(\cos(xe^x)-\ln(1-x)-x)^{1/x^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Find $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(\cos(xe^x)-\ln(1-x)-x)^{1/x^3}$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(\cos(xe^x)-\ln(1-x)-x)^{1/x^3}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos(xe^x)-\ln(1-x)-x)}{x^3}}$$

Using Taylor series:

$$\ln(\cos(xe^x)-\ln(1-x)-x)=\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}-x^3+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-x\right)=\ln(1-x^3)$$

Using L'Hospital's rule:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1-x^3)}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{3x^2}{x^3-1}}{3x^2}=-1\Rightarrow L=e^{-1}$$

This should not be the correct result.

Could someone check?

Comment: I have not done a full check, but we need one more term of the expansion of $\ln(1-x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. You rather have, as $x \to 0$, by standard Taylor expansions,
$$
\cos(xe^x)-\ln(1-x)-x=1-\frac{2 x^3}{3}+O(x^4)
$$ giving
$$
\frac1{x^3}\ln\left(\cos(xe^x)-\ln(1-x)-x\right)=\frac1{x^3}\ln\left(1-\frac{2 x^3}{3}+O(x^4)\right)=-\frac23+O(x)
$$ thus

> $$
> \lim\limits_{x\to 0}(\cos(xe^x)-\ln(1-x)-x)^{1/x^3}=e^{\large-\frac23}.
> $$